# Check if user can access an external resource cross-domain

Tags: jquery, dns, cross-domain, client-side

I need to check if a newly registered domain has fully registered/propagated from the users browser, so I can assure they have access to it.

I have full control over the site and need to check if something as simple as a text file exists on the target domain, and if it does we are good to go. I can edit both the requesting page and the target resource. I'm guessing this will have to be a jQuery ajax check of some sort.

I am unable to do this in PHP because although my servers DNS has propgated, the end users' may not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through a lot of heartache with this one and the same origin policy. In the end the most reliable/compatible way was to load an `<img>` tag with an image on the target server and check for the `.load` and `.error` handlers in jQuery. The gotcha was that you need to set the src of the img AFTER binding the error handler.

```
<img id="check" width="1" height="1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#check").error(function(){
        // It failed
    }).attr('src', 'http://domain.com/px.gif');

    $('#check').load(function() {
        // It worked
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant use AJAX Calls for that because it will get blocked by the same origin policy.

But you can use iframes instead:

```
<iframe id="check_1" src="http://www.wikipedia.com"></iframe>
<iframe id="check_2" src="http://www.aasdjflajsdflasdf.com"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('iframe#check_1').load(function() 
    {
        alert("check 1 succeeded!");
    });

    $('iframe#check_2').load(function() 
    {
        alert("check 2 succeeded!");
    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: He has full control over the site so he can add Access-Control-Request-Headers

Comment: This isn't working 100% of the time, possible to do with load order?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't mind throwing jQuery on your website, something like this should work as a framework:

```
$.ajax('http://www.example.com/text.txt', {
    success: function(result) {
        alert('User has access');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('User does not have status');
    }
});
```

Instead of rather those useless `alerts`, you could do this:

```
success: function() {
    $.get('http://1.1.1.1/user-has-access.php?access=true');
},
error: function() {
    $.get('http://1.1.1.1/user-has-access.php?access=false');
}
```